# Assign contents of Python dict to multiple variables at once?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to do something like this

```
def f():
    return { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 }

{ a, b } = f()     # or { 'a', 'b' } = f() ?
```

I.e. so that a gets assigned 1, b gets 2, and c is undefined

This is similar to this

```
def f()
    return( 1,2 )

a,b = f()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You already have the data in the dict, and can get it easily: `d=f(); d['a'] #...`  If you really wanna rebind the names: `d=f(); a,b=d['a'], d['b']`  Missing something?

Answer (score 12):

It wouldn't make any sense for unpacking to depend on the variable names. The closest you can get is:

```
a, b = [f()[k] for k in ('a', 'b')]
```

This, of course, evaluates `f()` twice.

---

You could write a function:

```
def unpack(d, *keys)
    return tuple(d[k] for k in keys)
```

Then do:

```
a, b = unpack(f(), 'a', 'b')
```

---

This is really all overkill though. Something simple would be better:

```
result = f()
a, b = result['a'], result['b']
```

Comment: Hmm... well thx @Eric, but the point is to avoid the redundancy of typing the variable names twice. I am just looking at the easiest way to go from dictionary to variables. A similar thing I would like to do would be something like this

`
table = [ {'a':1,'b':2 }, {'a':5, 'b':6 }, ... ]
for a,b in table:
    ...do something

rather than
for mydict in table:
    a,b = mydict['a'], mydict['b']
    ...do something
`

Comment: @cozycoding: Why do you need to? Leave the data in the dictionary!

Comment: @cozycoding: (WRT edit) If you use classes instead of dictionaries, you could do `for item in table: foo(item.a, item.b)`.

Answer (score 6):

Consider making `f` a `namedtuple` Then you can just use `f.a`, `f.b` directly

Answer (score 5):

Hmm. Kind of odd since a dictionary is not ordered, so the value unpacking depends on the variable names. But, it's possible, if ugly:

```
>>> locals().update(f())
>>> a
1
```

Don't try this at home! It's a maintainability nightmare. But kinda cool too :-)

Comment: Note that the python docs specifically state that you should not mutate the result of `locals()`. It might work okay now, but at some point in the future this code could throw an exception, or worse do something completely non-sensible.

Comment: @Geoff: Good to know. Even more reason not to use this :-)

Comment: @Cameron - count on me to avoid that! Thx

Comment: Modifying `locals()` doesn't work expect at the top namespace where `locals()` == `globals()`

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict = {'aa':2, 'bb':'john', 'cc':34, 'dd':'bye'}

a, b, c, d = [mydict[k] for k in ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use (or abuse) a function attribute to do this:

```
>>> def f():
...    f.a=1
...    f.b=2
...    return { 'a' : f.a, 'b' : f.b, 'c' : 3 }
... 
>>> f()
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> a,b=f.a,f.b
>>> a,b
(1, 2)
```

Be aware that the attributes only have value after f() is called or manually assigned.

I (rarely) use function attributes as a fill-in for C's `static` class variables like so:

```
>>> def f(i):
...    f.static+=i
...    return f.static
>>> f.static=0
>>> f(1)
1
>>> f(3)
4
```

There are better ways to do this, but just to be complete...