# Assign dictionary values to several variables in a single line (so I don't have to run the same funcion to generate the dictionary for each one)

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a function that returns a dictionary. The problem is that I want to assign the values of the dictionary to multiple variables, so I have to run the function several times. Is there a way to do this running the function only one time?
Is there any elegant way to do this?

```
def myFunction():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    d=4
    
    df_out={"a":a, "b":b,"c":c,"d":d}
    
a1=myFunction()["a"]
b1=myFunction()["b"]
c1=myFunction()["c"]
d1=myFunction()["d"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign contents of Python dict to multiple variables at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173607/assign-contents-of-python-dict-to-multiple-variables-at-once)

Comment: " so I have to run the function several times. " No you dont. re-use the value...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def myFunction():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    d=4

    return {"a":a, "b":b,"c":c,"d":d}

a1, b1, c1, d1 = myFunction().values()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result to a variable, then assign each variable.

```
d = myFunction()
a1 = d["a"]
b1 = d["b"]
c1 = d["c"]
d1 = d["d"]
```

I don't think there's a one-liner for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

i = itemgetter('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
a1, b1, c1, d1 = i(myFunction())

print(a1, b1, c1, d1)
```